# JavaScript, Ajax ,php parsererror, and How get post Json?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I got this code in game.php to refresh .refre, but I always get "parsererror". jsonString is from jsonString= JSON.stringify(object);

```
<div class="refre"></div>..
<script>...
        jsonString ={"right":0,"arrayQ":[{"0":"10","idQ":"19"},
            {"0":"34","idQ":"20"},{"0":"89","idQ":"14"}],"lives":40};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonString,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'Q.php',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

    }).done( function (data, status) {
        $('.refre').load('Q.php');
        alert('Right');
    })
    .fail( function (data, status) {
        alert("Wrong: "+status);
    });
        ...</script>
```

The other file is   Q.php, this read the POST and send some HTML, Now It is just for check the information of the POST.

```
<?php
$value = json_decode($_POST);
$categories = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

print_r($value);
print_r($categories);

?>
```

What's wrong with the ajax?? how I get the POST in Q.php? how can I get 'lives' from the JSON in Q.php?

Comment: look at the value returned by your ajax request using the network tab of your broswer's developer tools -> network tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div class="refre"></div>..
<script>...
        jsonString =[{"right":0,"arrayQ":[{"0":"10","idQ":"19"},
            {"0":"34","idQ":"20"},{"0":"89","idQ":"14"}],"lives":40}];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonString,
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'Q.php',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

    }).done( function (data, status) {
        $('.refre').html(data);
        alert('Right');
    })
    .fail( function (data, status) {
        alert("Wrong: "+status);
    });

    ...</script>
```

---

```
<?php
$value = json_decode($_POST);
$categories = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

print_r($value);
print_r($categories);

?>
```

Comment: If you replace `dataType: 'json',` with `dataType: 'html',`, will the data be sent as JSON? I mean, does this change means that we lose the advantages of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

What you call `jsonString` is not JSON, it is a javscript object.

When you pass an object to `data` of `$.ajax` , jQuery will form encode that data.

In php you would retrieve `lives` using `$_POST['lives']`. **It is not being sent as JSON**

Think of the keys in the object as `name` of a form input.

As for your output, you can only ever return one JSON string from server. The JSON must have one set of open/close braces so it can be turned into one array or object

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="refre"></div>
<script>
    jsonString =[{"right":0,"arrayQ":[{"0":"10","idQ":"19"},{"0":"34","idQ":"20"},{"0":"89","idQ":"14"}],"lives":40}];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonString,
        url: 'Q.php',
    }).done( function (data, status) {
        $('.refre').html(data);
        alert('Right');
    })
    .fail( function (data, status) {
        alert("Wrong: "+status);
    });
</script>
```

Q.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This is OK. The 'data' will not be send as json. $_POST is an array in Q.php, you don't need to json_decode it.